# How do I run/src an HTML file inside another (or a div)?

Tags: html

I am trying to src an html file inside another but preferably inside the div of another html file. I tied using the following:

```
 <? include("./NavigationTree.html"); ?>
```

but nothing happened. The html files are located in the same folder. And am trying to run the file in the container-inner div.
 Here is my div code:

```
<div class="container-outer">
<div class="container-inner">
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: change your file extension to php, and make your first line read `<?php include(...); ?>`, where `...` is the filename

Comment: Rename NavigationTree.html to NavigationTree.php

Comment: @bobek, it won't help any if his main file isn't php.

Comment: use php or ssi.  there is no native html "include" option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using jQuery. [.load() method](https://api.jquery.com/load/) Then it will be a simple client-side JavaScript call:

```
$('.container-inner').load('./NavigationTree.html');
```

Answer (score 1):

- A number of server side tools can do this (Apache Velocity, Java Server Pages, PHP and many others).
- jQuery and maybe some other client-side JavaScript tools can also do.
- HTML supports iframe that allows to include pages one inside another, but I would advise against using it just to organize the website content.
- It may be possible to find generating tools that would build static content including one file into another before it can be uploaded to the server.

Simple static HTML itself cannot be easily included one into another without rather clumsy and relatively complex JavaScript workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using an [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)

> The HTML  Element (or HTML inline frame element) represents a nested browsing context, effectively embedding another HTML page into the current page. In HTML 4.01, a document may contain a head and a body or a head and a frame-set, but not both a body and a frame-set. However,an  can be used within a normal document body. Each browsing context has its own session history and active document. The browsing context that contains the embedded content is called the parent browsing context. The top-level browsing context (which has no parent) is typically the browser window.

Comment: I have upvoted to neutralize -1. What is exactly so horrible with iframe?